# Why is the same ggplot2 Code creating Plots with different labels?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am new to R programming and just finished my first Data Analysis project on Rstudio. This is my first question on Stack Overflow and I am not sure if these details are enough. I am happy to edit if guided by those with more experience. Should I change the names of the dataframe and/or the variables to make this easier?

The problem: I used the following code to create a plot with % labels reflecting members vs casual two weeks ago. Attached image to illustrate this.

Bar graph with showing % values by member vs casual:

[image]

Surprised to see the plot created using the same code now where the % values are that of months instead of member/casual.

Bar graph showing % values by month:

[image]

```
Divvy22_clean %>% 
  group_by(start_mth, member_casual) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(count = n()) %>% 
  mutate(percent = count/sum(count)*100) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(start_mth, count, fill = member_casual)) + 
  geom_col(position = "stack") + 
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(round(percent), "%")), 
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), size = 3, color = "white") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 900000), expand = c(0, 0)) + 
  labs(x = "Months, 2022", y = "Total Rentals", 
       title = "Ride Distribution by Month and Membership Type")+
  facet_wrap(~member_casual)
```

If you need to simulate the problem, I hope the following codes help with that:

```
set.seed(123) 

start_mth <- rep(c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar"), each = 2)
member_casual <- rep(c("member", "casual"), times = 3)
count <- round(runif(6, 0, 900000))
Divvy_example <- data.frame(start_mth, member_casual, count)

# Calculate percentages
Divvy_example <- Divvy_example %>% 
  group_by(start_mth, member_casual) %>% 
  mutate(percent = count/sum(count) * 100)

# Plot 
ggplot(Divvy_example, aes(start_mth, count, fill = member_casual)) + 
  geom_col(position = "stack") + 
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(round(percent), "%")), 
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), size = 3, color = "white") + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 900000), expand = c(0, 0)) + 
  labs(x = "Months, 2022", y = "Total Rentals", 
       title = "Ride Distribution by Month and Membership Type") +
  facet_wrap(~member_casual)
```

Also, I have updated R to the latest version two days ago. That's the only change I have made. Also, another details that may be relevant is that when this code was creating the first plot with member/casual values in RStudio, it was creating the plot with % values by month on Kaggle, just like what it's doing now on the updated R Studio.

I am trying to learn more about R. It would be very helpful to know what's leading to this inconsistency and how can I get the graph with % values by member/casual. Thanks for your help!

I am trying to understand the reasons behind this inconsistency, since this code has worked several times in the past month. Is the syntax affected by updated versions of R and if that happens, what is the way to avoid it? Or is there a different reason why I am experiencing this inconsistency?

Comment: I don't think the code for those two plots was identical. One give-away for me is the gap below 0 on the y-axis in the second plot. This gap appears by default and a modification to the y-axis scale must be made to remove the gap. That was clearly done in the first plot. The y-axis scale modification could also be used to change the min and max values of the y-axis.

Comment: One possibility is that you've updated `dplyr` between these two runs and the dropping of groups has differed between these two. Would you be able to post/simulate some example data to try this with? it's tricky to trace the problem without data to experiment with.

Comment: Also the y-axis label, "Rides" in the code and in the second plot, "TotalRentals" in the first plot.

Comment: Your top chart has percents calculated on ungrouped data, which you'd get with `dplyr 1.1.0` if your 3rd line were `summarise(count = n(), .groups = "drop") %>%`. Your lower chart has percents calculated on data grouped by `start_mth`, which corresponds to the syntax `summarise(count = n(), .groups = "drop_last") %>%`, where summarize drops the last grouping variable, but keeps any prior ones. This was the only supported behavior of `summarise` before v1.0.0.

Comment: @qdread That is an excellent observation. Thanks for highlighting that. I did make a mistake in sharing the code (apologies). The codes are slightly different in that the y axis like you mentioned is adjusted with scale_y_continuous(). But the rest of the calculation looks the same to me. Any idea why the results are inconsistent?

Comment: @qdread Here is the correct complete code: Divvy22_clean %>% group_by(start_mth, member_casual) %>% dplyr::summarise(count = n()) %>% mutate(percent = count/sum(count)*100) %>% ggplot(aes(start_mth, count, fill = member_casual)) +  geom_col(position = "stack") + geom_text(aes(label = paste0(round(percent), "%")), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5),  size = 3, color = "white") + scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 900000), expand = c(0, 0)) + labs(x = "Months, 2022", y = "Total Rentals", title = "Ride Distribution by Month and Membership Type")

Comment: @GregorThomas Thanks for the catch. See reply to qdread for an explanation.

Comment: @JonSpring I was not aware of this feature and so never used these .groups = "drop". I just tried them both anyway and the result is still by month.

Comment: ^ `.groups` was added to summarize in dplyr 1.0.0 in june 2020, so if you are getting the same behavior either way that makes me suspect you are using an earlier version. You could upgrade or add `ungroup() %>%` in the following line if you want the subsequent calculation to be ungrouped.

Comment: @AndyBaxter I did update R after creating the first chart. That would update dplyr as too, I suppose. I don't really know how to create a code to simulate but I tried this code on R which is creating the same type of plot with 3 months. Do let me know if it helps or does not help:

Comment: @AndyBaxter set.seed(123)

start_mth <- rep(c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar"), each = 2)
member_casual <- rep(c("member", "casual"), times = 3)
count <- round(runif(6, 0, 900000))

Divvy_example <- data.frame(start_mth, member_casual, count)

# Calculate percentages
Divvy_example <- Divvy_example %>%
  group_by(start_mth, member_casual) %>%
  mutate(percent = count/sum(count) * 100)

Comment: @AndyBaxter # Plot
ggplot(Divvy_example, aes(start_mth, count, fill = member_casual)) +
  geom_col(position = "stack") +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(round(percent), "%")), 
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), 
            size = 3, color = "white") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 900000), expand = c(0, 0)) +
  labs(x = "Months, 2022", y = "Total Rentals", 
       title = "Ride Distribution by Month and Membership Type")    Apologize for multiple comments. I am not sure if there is a way to share the whole comment in one box. I will try to find out. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @JonSpring Sorry but that is not the case. I downloaded R and RStudion this year in Feb and updated in April, just a few days ago. The first graph was created in Mar 2023 and the second in April 2023 with the latest version.

Comment: @LisaH instead of putting the code in comments, please edit your question with the corrected code.

Comment: @qdread I have updated the question. but it did not allow me to insert the image (I don't have enough credits, it says). But it's there as a link. I have also attempted a simulation right below that first code, if that helps. Thanks for guiding me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some simulated data showing the problem (the problem is in the `summarise` part which creates `count` so have started from some fresh data before counting).

In the top graph which replicates your second, incorrectly calculated graph, the `.groups = "drop"` argument then has an ungrouped output. The second graph with `.groups = "drop_last"` drops the `member_casual` grouping and then calculates percentages by `start_mth`, which I think is what you intend to do? These defaults may have changed between the running of your two graphs, so if you state `.groups = "drop_last"` specifically then this will keep it consistent.

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(123)

df <-
  tibble(
    start_mth = sample(
      month.abb,
      size = 1000,
      replace = TRUE,
      prob = c(1:6, 6:1)
    ),
    member_casual = sample(
      c("member", "casual"),
      1000,
      replace = TRUE
    )
  ) %>% 
  mutate(start_mth = factor(start_mth, levels = month.abb))

df %>% 
group_by(start_mth, member_casual) %>% 
  summarise(count = n(), .groups = "drop") %>% 
  mutate(percent = count/sum(count)*100) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(start_mth, count, fill = member_casual)) + 
  geom_col(position = "stack") + 
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(round(percent), "%")), 
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), size = 3, color = "white") +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(add = c(0, 10))) + 
  labs(x = "Months, 2022", y = "Total Rentals", 
       title = "Ride Distribution by Month and Membership Type")+
  facet_wrap(~member_casual)
```

[image]

```r
df %>% 
  group_by(start_mth, member_casual) %>% 
  summarise(count = n(), .groups = "drop_last") %>% 
  mutate(percent = count/sum(count)*100) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(start_mth, count, fill = member_casual)) + 
  geom_col(position = "stack") + 
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(round(percent), "%")), 
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), size = 3, color = "white") +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(add = c(0, 10))) + 
  labs(x = "Months, 2022", y = "Total Rentals", 
       title = "Ride Distribution by Month and Membership Type") +
  facet_wrap(~member_casual)
```

[image]

### Extra tip - get `ggplot` to do calculations for you

With the help of a few extra `ggplot2` functions, you can drop the `group_by`, `summarise` and `mutate` lines and pass in the unaltered dataframe to `ggplot` directly.

- The first `stat_count` will count the observations by category and return bars
- The second `stat_count` constructs the labels by calculating proportions across each `x` value: `sapply(x, FUN = function(month) ...)` does the calcs for each month on the `x` axis

In general, it's good practice to feed the unaltered, tidy `data.frame` into `ggplot` and let it do the work for you, but this is a tip of minor importance if you have working code you understand already!

```r
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(start_mth, fill = member_casual)) +
  stat_count() +
  stat_count(aes(label = paste0(round(
                   after_stat(count) / 
                     sapply(x, FUN = function(month)
                       sum(count[x == month])
                   ) * 100
                 ), "%")),
             geom = "text",
             position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5),
             size = 3, color = "white") +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(add = c(0, 10))) + 
  labs(x = "Months, 2022", y = "Total Rentals", 
       title = "Ride Distribution by Month and Membership Type") +
  facet_wrap( ~ member_casual)
```

[image]

### Edit - grouping in example code

The key thing to note is that when calculating %s by month the grouping should **only** be by `start_mth`. Stating this in `group_by` between generating counts and percentages will fix this in all circumstances:

```r
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(123) 

start_mth <- rep(c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar"), each = 2)
member_casual <- rep(c("member", "casual"), times = 3)
count <- round(runif(6, 0, 900000))
Divvy_example <- data.frame(start_mth, member_casual, count)

# Calculate percentages
Divvy_example <- Divvy_example %>% 
  group_by(start_mth) %>%  # Group **only** by start_mth
  mutate(percent = count/sum(count) * 100)

# Plot 
ggplot(Divvy_example, aes(start_mth, count, fill = member_casual)) + 
  geom_col(position = "stack") + 
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(round(percent), "%")), 
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), size = 3, color = "white") + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 900000), expand = c(0, 0)) + 
  labs(x = "Months, 2022", y = "Total Rentals", 
       title = "Ride Distribution by Month and Membership Type") +
  facet_wrap(~member_casual)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for working on this problem. .groups = "drop" or "drop_last" have no effect; getting the same graph with % in months (I need the second graph you got with "drop_last"). Could it have anything to do with the version of RStudio or any feature? I did a Google search for this problem but had no luck. This is probably insignificant, so please ignore this point but my original code worked on the previous R version to generate the graph by member/casual without using .groups.
Appreciate the extra tip; that does give me the graph I need.

Comment: The key thing either way is that in the calculation of %s by month the dataframe should be grouped only as `group_by(start_mth)` (after generating counts). The `summarise(..., .drop = )` parts are one possible explanation of why it's not working. If you use `group_by(start_mth)` though it should work in all circumstances (demonstration above). Hope that helps!

Comment: Restarting was a game-changer. Only R knows how R works!  Your solution with .groups finally worked. Someone else also suggested this same solution but RStuio here was not honoring it. Thanks a lot Andy!